# c# call method in other class

Tags: c#, class, interface

im relatively new to c#. i have the class at the bottom that has the sender.send() command. i need to call this from the first class, and pass it the 'outbound' that i have created so it will do the sender.send bit - please help.
For info ISender is an interface, and Handler and Publisher are classes.

```
class CVHandler : Handler<CVRequest>
{
    protected override object Do(CVRequest Body, object previousResult)
    {   Message outbound = new Message(Body);
        outbound.Key = "PM";

        //Send the message

        return null;
    }
}

public class CVPublisher : Publisher
{
    protected override void Do(ISender sender)
    {
        sender.Send(message);
    }
}
```

Comment: you need to the Do method Internal or public to access it from the first class.

Answer (score 1):

When defining a method as `protected`, it can only be used by this class and its subclasses. This is why you can't call it from `CVHandler`.

Comment: Hi,Yes ok that gives me access to it. Thanks. I then get the issue that if i try this             CVPublisher sending = new CVPublisher();
            sending.Do(message); it tells me that its expecting type ISender - and not type Message which is what I have built as my 'outbound'

Comment: Hi, I suggest you edit your question with the new code or better yet, open another one with relevant code and exact error. It's harder to read it as a comment.